# Can't add a new activity on android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to improve my android development skills, so working on some project about it. In my project, I added a new "Navigation Drawer Activity", then I deleted it because I wanted to create a new one but I can not able to add even another type of activitiy. Android studio adds ,

```
<activity
        android:name=".ExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
```

tag in AndroidManifest.xml but It doesn't create any classes and xml layout files.
Also studio says:

> ide internal error occurred android studio.

I tried regenerate `R.java` and clean my project ,but it doesn't work. How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Do you mean to say you created an activity deleted it but studio didn't clean up the manifest? Well you can just delete that bit of code by hand.

Comment: I created an activity then deleted it, after that I tried to add a new activity but it doesn't add. It just add activity tags to project's AndroidManifest.xml but doesn't create Activity classes and layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not find a exact solution to that problem.  Re-installed the Android Studio . It does the solution manually

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a simple JavaClass and write an "extends Activity" behind the class name. And put this new Activity in the Manifest like in your example. You can add a menu and a layout like this, too, when you add xml-Files in the layout and menu folders. This should work.

Comment: I know I can do it like you said. But I want Android Studio to do it automatically from  New-> Activity menu  .

Answer (score 0):

If it's about how Activities is not showing up as an option in either the shortcut menu in the Layout folder or File + New in the menu, you can try File + "Sync Project with Gradle files" and give it some time.
This also adds options to the Tools menu (great if AVD or SDK Manager is missing).